# Auto Fit Row and Column not working with Jasper Report?

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I am facing a problem with JasperReports. I am trying to auto-fit rows and columns in an Excel sheet. I am setting these properties, but somehow it is not working. The Excel cell height is not automatically configured based on the text inside that cell.

```
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border", "false");
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows", "true");
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns", "true");
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text", "true");
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row", "true");
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column", "true");
```

Please share if you have any idea why the problem is happening.

Note: The version I am using is 4.5.1 and the same JRXML is getting used to generate Excel as well as PDF documents.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same issue, because I'm not familiar with Jasper Print, but I know that the Auto Fit cell height does not work in Excel when the cell that contains what would be multiple lines of text is a merged cell. Excel simply set's the row height to the default row height. If there are cells to the left or right of the merged cell and they happen to contain enough text to cause the row height to be expanded then that works but not when the cell that requires the maximum height is a set of merged cells